# How do I create a folder in a Red5 application folder using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, red5

When I record video using a Webcam, it gets recorded as an `.flv` file in the streams folder of the app that I'm using. Eg - `path/to/red5/webapps/vod/streams`

I want to create a directory in `streams` and store the file there. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Just append folder name at the end of the server url of netconnection object.

`var folder_name = "yourfolder";`

`var netConnection=new NetConnection;`

`netConnection.connect(serverUrl+folder_name);`

Then your recordings will be saved into the location streams\yourfolder.

In your case path/to/red5/webapps/vod/streams/yourfolder

Hope this helps.